# Grouping dynamic JSON Keys using map and reduce if possible javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I want to group Dynamic Object keys of a json. The object values from each keys will be group to their respective key.

I tried using map and reduce to group it but the results are not grouped as I expected.

Here is my JSON Object

```
var data = [
  {
    "type": 6,
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "cause": {
          "root": {
            "Extracted": {
              "Body": {
                "Error": {
                  "ErrorCode": "143",
                  "ErrorString": "NotFound",
                  "info": {
                    "Error": {
                      "errorDesc": "Data Not Found",
                      "subs": {
                        "attrib": {
                          "subs_name": "123com",
                          "subs_no": 4
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "type": 6,
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "cause": {
          "root": {
            "Extracted": {
              "Body": {
                "Error": {
                  "ErrorCode": "143",
                  "ErrorString": "NotFound",
                  "info": {
                    "Error": {
                      "errorDesc": "Company Not Found",
                      "subs": {
                        "attrib": {
                          "subs_name": "QRS",
                          "subs_no": 4
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "type": 6,
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "cause": {
          "root": {
            "Extracted": {
              "Body": {
                "Error": {
                  "ErrorCode": "123",
                  "ErrorString": "SystemFailure",
                  "info": {
                    "Error": {
                      "errorDesc": "Internal server error",
                      "subs": {
                        "attrib": {
                          "subs_name": "ABC",
                          "subs_no": 2
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "type": 6,
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "cause": {
          "root": {
            "Extracted": {
              "Body": {
                "Error": {
                  "ErrorCode": "123",
                  "ErrorString": "SystemFailure",
                  "info": {
                    "Error": {
                      "errorDesc": "Insufficient Data",
                      "subs": {
                        "attrib": {
                          "subs_name": "DEF",
                          "subs_no": 3
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "type": 6,
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "cause": {
          "root": {
            "Extracted": {
              "Body": {
                "Error": {
                  "ErrorCode": "999",
                  "ErrorString": "Unknown",
                  "info": {
                    "Unknown": {
                      "desc": "UnknownError",
                      "subs": "GHI"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": true
  }
]
```

This is the code that I have tried but didn't get the result I want

```
var x = data.map((e) => {
  var el = {}
    el[e.data.error.cause.root.Extracted.Body.Error.ErrorString] = 
    [e.data.error.cause.root.Extracted.Body.Error.info];

    return el;
  })

 console.log(x);
```

The result I got:

```
 [
   {
     "NotFound": {....}
   },
   {
     "NotFound": {....}
   },
   {
     "SystemFailure": {....}
   },
   {
     "SystemFailure": {....}
   },
   {
     "Unknown": {....}
   },
 ]
```

The result I expect:

```
[
 {
   "NotFound": [
     {
       "Error": {
         "errorDesc": "Data Not Found",
         "subs": {
           "attrib": {
              "subs_name": "123com",
              "subs_no": 4
         }
       }
     },
     {
       "Error": {
         "errorDesc": "Company Not Found",
         "subs": {
         "attrib": {
            "subs_name": "QRS",
            "subs_no": 4
         }
       }
     }
   }
  ]
 },
 { 
   "SystemFailure": [
      {
       "Error": {
          "errorDesc": "Internal server error",
          "subs": {
              "attrib": {
              "subs_name": "ABC",
              "subs_no": 2
            }
          }
      },
      {
        "Error": {
            "errorDesc": "Insufficient Data",
            "subs": {
               "attrib": {
                  "subs_name": "DEF",
                  "subs_no": 3
               }
            }
      }
   ]
 },
 {
    "Unknown": [
       {
          "Unknown": {
            "desc": "UnknownError",
            "subs": "GHI"
          }
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `reduce` the array. Create an accumulator object with unique `ErrorString` as key. Set the value to be an object with the same `ErrorString` as key. Then add each `info` object based on the `ErrorString`. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) get the grouped values as an array

```js
const data=[{type:6,data:{error:{cause:{root:{Extracted:{Body:{Error:{ErrorCode:"143",ErrorString:"NotFound",info:{Error:{errorDesc:"Data Not Found",subs:{attrib:{subs_name:"123com",subs_no:4}}}}}}}}}}},status:true},{type:6,data:{error:{cause:{root:{Extracted:{Body:{Error:{ErrorCode:"143",ErrorString:"NotFound",info:{Error:{errorDesc:"Company Not Found",subs:{attrib:{subs_name:"QRS",subs_no:4}}}}}}}}}}},status:true},{type:6,data:{error:{cause:{root:{Extracted:{Body:{Error:{ErrorCode:"123",ErrorString:"SystemFailure",info:{Error:{errorDesc:"Internal server error",subs:{attrib:{subs_name:"ABC",subs_no:2}}}}}}}}}}},status:true},{type:6,data:{error:{cause:{root:{Extracted:{Body:{Error:{ErrorCode:"123",ErrorString:"SystemFailure",info:{Error:{errorDesc:"Insufficient Data",subs:{attrib:{subs_name:"DEF",subs_no:3}}}}}}}}}}},status:true},{type:6,data:{error:{cause:{root:{Extracted:{Body:{Error:{ErrorCode:"999",ErrorString:"Unknown",info:{Unknown:{desc:"UnknownError",subs:"GHI"}}}}}}}}},status:true}];

const merged = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const e = o.data.error.cause.root.Extracted.Body.Error;
  acc[e.ErrorString] = acc[e.ErrorString] || { [e.ErrorString]: [] };
  acc[e.ErrorString][e.ErrorString].push(e.info)
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you @adiga !  Can you explain to me how the code works per line? by commenting on the code? Im not really familiar on how to use reduce in json.